# Win-loss ratios, and averages of them

Tags: statistics

There are many games where player performance is ranked by ratio of wins to losses.

I mistakenly had it in my head that the average such ratio must be 1. This is not the case, as can be found from a simple example:

```
W   L   W:L
-----------
7   2   3.5
3   3   1
3   6   0.5
4   2   2
2   2   1
1   5   0.2
-----------
sum sum avg
20  20  1.37
```

My question is this: assuming that the numbers come from a closed system, and so the total number of wins is always equal to the total number of losses, is there some way to get a result as "obvious" as I was incorrectly expecting? Perhaps there's some way to scale such ratios, whereby by averaging them you'll always get a constant?

Or to get such a result do you always need to know the absolute number of wins and losses per person? For example, I could award +1 point for a win and -1 for a loss, and then the average score is always going to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this explicit question is "no"

> is there some way to get a result as "obvious" as I was incorrectly
> expecting?

if you want to use W:L ratios. To see that, imagine a tournament in which one player wins all their games. Then their W:L ratio has a zero denominator, which is trouble.

If each of $n$ participants plays exactly $g$ games then the average of the *winning ratios* $W_i/g$ for the $n$ players will be $1/n$. So for example with four players each player wins $25/%$ of their games - on average.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured this out.

If I map the ratios to the range 0 to 2 like this:

- For ratios 0 through 1, $f(x) = x$
- For ratios 1 through infinity, $f(x) = 2 - (1/x)$

I think the average of these mapped ratios is always 1. But I don't know how to verify this mathematically.